# Xcode Constraining UILabel vertically over a dynamic UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, xcode6, interface-builder, uilabel

I am trying to constrain a label that is sitting on top a UIImageView. The ImageView keeps its aspect ratio for the different screen sizes so its length and width change according to the device.

I am running into an issue if I constrain the top of the label to the top of the image view at (for example) a constant of 58. For the lower resolution image that places the label where I want it visually. However on the higher resolution images that position is not where I want it visually. I have also tried adjusting the top constraint so that the constant is 0 and use the multiplier to adjust the position of the label. This however does not fix the problem and the label ends up at different locations on the image.

I really would not like to have to edit these constraints programmatically as I will have way more labels on different view controllers that would be a pain to program. Really hoping I can achieve this in IB.

[image: Using multiplier based constraint]

[image: Resulting layout from multiplier based constraint]

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused... why aren't you pinning a constant distance from the top of the label to the bottom of the image view?

Comment: When I put a constant distance for the constraint it still shows up at a different place on the imageView depending on the resolution

Comment: One way you might be able to resolve this is by adding an extra "blank" view at the top of your image view, with constraints to stay at a constant scale and to expand based on the width.  Then you could pin the top of your label to the bottom of the "blank" view.